# Unicode Error in Python 3 in Windows

Tags: python, windows, unicode, syntax

job = my_cron.new(command ="C:\Users\Suave Bajaj\Desktop\MAS.3\FeedParser_1.py")
                              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

I have Tried:

1. Double Back Slashes:
   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
2. Forward Slashes with r:
   job = my_cron.new(command =r "C:/Users/Suave Bajaj/Desktop/MAS.3/FeedParser_1.py")
                                                                                   ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I can't tell why the file was not found (your path apparently doesn't exist. The error with `r` is that you put a space between the `r` and the opening quote.

Comment: @GhostlyMartijn The Path very much exits, and removing the space between 'r' and the opening quote gives an **FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**

Comment: Yet the system tells you it doesn't. Try `os.listdir()` on the directory and verify what is listed. If that fails, remove the last part of the path and try again until you have a working base path. Then figure out your mistake from there, working your way up to the original file.